# Efficiency in assigning programmatically in R

Tags: r, assign

In summary, I have a script for importing lots of data stored in several txt files. In a sigle file **not** all the rows are to be put in the same table (DF now switching to DT), so for each file I select all the rows belonging to the same DF, `get` DF and `assign` to it the rows.

The first time I create a DF named ,say, table1 I do:

```
name <- "table1" # in my code the value of name will depend on different factors
                 # and **not** known in advance
assign(name, someRows)
```

Then, during the execution my code may find (in other files) other lines to be put in the table1 data frame, so:

```
name <- "table"
assign(name, rbindfill(get(name), someRows))
```

My question is: is `assign(get(string), anyObject)` the best way for doing assignment programmatically? Thanks

EDIT:

here is a simplified version of my code: (each item in `dataSource` is the result of `read.table()` so one single text file)

```
set.seed(1)
#
dataSource <- list(data.frame(fileType = rep(letters[1:2], each=4),
                              id       = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=2),
                              var1     = as.integer(rnorm(8))),
                   data.frame(fileType = rep(letters[1:2], each=4),
                              id       = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=2),
                              var1     = as.integer(rnorm(8))))
#                   #                                                                                          #
#                          
library(plyr)
#
tablesnames <- unique(unlist(lapply(dataSource,function(x) as.character(unique(x[,1])))))
for(l in tablesnames){
  temp <- lapply(dataSource, function(x) x[x[,1]==l, -1])
  if(exists(l)) assign(l, rbind.fill(get(l), rbind.fill(temp))) else assign(l, rbind.fill(temp))
}
#
#            
# now two data frames a and b are crated
#
#
# different method using rbindlist in place of rbind.fill (faster and, until now, I don't # have missing column to fill)
#
rm(a,b)
library(data.table)
#
tablesnames <- unique(unlist(lapply(dataSource,function(x) as.character(unique(x[,1])))))
for(l in tablesnames){
  temp <- lapply(dataSource, function(x) x[x[,1]==l, -1])
  if(exists(l)) assign(l, rbindlist(list(get(l), rbindlist(temp)))) else assign(l, rbindlist(temp))
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand your question, but will say that you probably shouldn't use neither `get` nor `assign`. If you gave a reproducible example, people could show you better way to deal with your data.

Comment: @Roland Hi, I've edited my question. What you don't actually understand?

Comment: @Roland the reproducible example is ready!

Comment: Along the same lines as Paul's answer, I think: avoid dynamically growing something by binding it in a loop.

Comment: @Frank which means? have you fully read my post?

Comment: I mean that if you follow his advice (operating on a list instead of looping), you can avoid `rbindlist`/`rbindfill` as well as `assign` and `get`. Your `rbinds` and twice copying into `temp` are probably quite important for performance. I may be wrong; I am not a computer scientist. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for answering. You're right, and I **do** know what you and @Paul mean. But, the issue is: I have in **different** text files pieces of what has to be (at the end of the import process) a **single** `data.frame` or `data.table`. Does it make sense? 

(`temp` is the list of all the imported txt file)

Comment: I think I would approach your problem by first coming up with a list of names of valid files and then `do.call(rbind,lapply(my_list,get))` or something similar. In fact, I have done this (with csvs exported from SAS) quite a lot lately, tying together a series of data sets with slightly different variables collected each year. If we're all still misunderstanding your question, maybe you could try splitting it up into smaller questions?

Comment: @Frank thanks your comment starts to look like a proper answer :-). I'm sorry, I thought it was a common task people deal with, but I just supposed incorrectly.. I'll try to re write the question much clearer

Comment: This is actually a very common task, and the suggestion in my answer is an effective way of dealing with it.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thanks, but I still think you are missing my point a little bit. I can't take txt files and push them all directly in one `df` as they are. Like I said, I thought I was clear, I'll re write the question, my fault.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a named `list`, and skip using `assign` and `get`. Many of the cool R features (`lapply` for example) work very well on lists, and do not work with using `assign` and `get`. In addition, you can easily pass lists in to a function, while this can be somewhat cumbersome with groups of variables combined with `assign` and `get`.

If you want to read a set of files into one big data.frame I'd use something like this (assuming csv like text files):

```
library(plyr)
list_of_files = list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
big_dataframe = ldply(list_of_files, read.csv)
```

or if you want to keep the result in a list:

```
big_list = lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)
```

and possibly use `rbind.fill`:

```
big_dataframe = do.call("rbind.fill", big_list)
```

Comment: I'm adding an example... one sec

Comment: Have you checked my edit? I know what you saying, it's obvious.., but I don't think it's applicable in my case..

Comment: @Michele Perhaps it's too obvious.  He's suggesting that you assign to names in a list and reference that, rather than assigning to names in the global environment.  Reading your code, there is no reason that you can't use a list.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg the reason is: I would like all these small pieces imported from different txt file to be in one **single** dataframe. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you want them to be in one single data.frame you can simply append the individual datasets, e.g. using `rbind`.

Comment: Please read carefully my question. I said: "In a sigle file not all the rows are to be put in the same table "

Comment: Then either use `rbind.fill` or keep the data in a list.

Comment: I already use `rbind.fill`... to push into a `df` all the element of the list called `temp` which contains the text files (after filtering the rows I need) in its elements.

Comment: Then I would recommend you ditch the `assign` based reading, and switch to `lapply` + `rbind.fill`.

Comment: I put a sample data in my question. Can I see your method in action? I mean, could you edit your answer using the dummy data I've given in the question. Otherwise it'll too chatty :-)