# Best way to name objects programmatically using R?

Tags: r, loops, variable-assignment

I'm running various modeling algorithms on a data set. I've had best results by modeling my input variables to my responses one at a time, e.g.:

```
model <- train(y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + xn, ...)
```

Once I train my models, I'd like to not re-run them each time, so I've been trying to save them as `.rda` files. Here's an example loop for a random forest model (feel free to suggest a better way than a loop!):

```
# data_resp contains my measured responses, one per column
# data_pred contains my predictors, one per column

for (i in 1:ncol(data_resp)) {

  model <- train(data_pred_scale[!is.na(data_resp[, i]), ],
                 data_resp[!is.na(data_resp[, i]), i],
                 method = "rf",
                 tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = c(3:6)),
                 nodesize = 3,
                 ntrees = 500)

  save(model, file = paste("./models/model_rf_", names(data_resp)[i], ".rda", sep = ""))
```

When I load the model, however, it's going to be called `model`.

I haven't found a good way to save the model with it's corresponding name to try and refer back to it later. I found that one can assign an object to a string like so:

```
assign(paste("./models/model_rf_", names(data_resp)[i], ".rda", sep = ""), train(...))
```

But I'm still left with how to refer to the object when I save it:

```
save(???, file = ...)
```

I don't know how to call the object by it's custom name.

Lastly, even loading has presented a problem. I've tried `assign("model_name", load("./model.rda"))`, but the resultant object, called `string` ends up just holding a string of the object name, "model".

---

In looking around, I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542781/efficiency-in-assigning-programmatically-in-r) question, which seems relevant, but I'm trying to figure out how to apply it to my situation.

I could create a list with the names of each column name in `data_resp` (my measured responses) and then use `lapply` to use `train()`, but I'm still a bit stuck on how to dynamically refer to the new object name to keep the resultant model in.

Comment: Your specific question about save() could have been answered by simply reading the documentation and noting the second argument.

Comment: Try to use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` in that case, it'll simplify a lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

When you save the model, save another object called 'name' which is a character string of the thing you want to name it as:

```
> d=data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))
> model=lm(y~x,data=d)
> name="m1"
> save(model,name,file="save1.rda")
> d=data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))
> model=lm(y~x,data=d)
> name="m2"
> save(model,name,file="save2.rda")
```

Now each file knows what it wants its resulting object to be called. How do you get that back on load? Load into a new environment, and assign:

```
> e=new.env()
> load("save1.rda",env=e)
> assign(e$name,e$model)
> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d)
```

You can now safely rm or re-use the 'e' object. You can of course wrap this in a function:

```
> blargh=function(f){e=new.env();load(f,env=e);assign(e$name,e$model,.GlobalEnv)}
> blargh("save2.rda")
> m2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d)
```

Note this is a double bad thing to do - firstly, you should probably store all the models in one file as a list with names. Secondly, this function has side effects, and if you had an object called `m2` already it would get stomped on.

Using `assign` like this is nearly always a sign (dyswidt?) that you should use a list instead.

B

Answer (score 1):

There is a fair amount of guesswork involved in this answer but I think this could help:

```
# get a vector with the column names in data_resp
modNames <- colnames( data_resp )

# create empty list
models <- as.list( NULL )

# iterate through your columns and assign the result as list members
for( n in modNames )
{
  models[[n]] <- train(data_pred_scale[!is.na(data_resp[, n]), ],  ### this may need modification, can't test without data
                 data_resp[!is.na(data_resp[, n]), n],
                 method = "rf",
                 tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = c(3:6)),
                 nodesize = 3,
                 ntrees = 500)
}

# save the whole bunch
save( models, file = "models.rda" )
```

You can now retrieve, just with `load( "models.rda )`, this one object, the list with all your models, and address them with list notation, either as `models[[1]]` or with the column name, eg. `models[["first"]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers about doing this with a loop are great. I used this as a chance to finally try and understand `lapply` better, as many of the StackOverflow questions about how to do this ended up suggesting the use of lists and `lapply` instead of loops.

I really like the idea of combining all results of `train()` into a list (which @vaettchen did in his loop), and in thinking about how to do this with a list, this is what I came up with. First, I needed my data.frame in list form, one entry per column. Since I don't really work with lists, I hunted around until just trying `as.list(df)`, which worked like a charm.

Next, I want to apply my train function to each element of my list of measured response variables, so I defined the function like this:

```
# predictors are stored in data_pred
# responses are in data_resp (one per column)
# rows in data_pred/data_resp (perhaps obviously) match, one per observation

train_func <- function(y) { train(x = data_pred, y = y,
   method = "rf", tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = 3:6),
   ntrees = 500) }
```

Now I just need to use `lapply` to apply the `train()` call on each element of `data_resp`. I didn't know how to create an empty, placeholder list, so thanks to @vaettchen for that (I was trying `list_name <- list()` without success):

```
models <- lapply(as.list(data_resp), train_func)
```

Awesomely, I found that `models` has it's elements automatically named to my column names in `data_resp`, which is just fantastic. I'm using this in conjunction with the `shiny` package, so this will make it incredibly easy for the user to select a response variable from a drop down (which can store the response variable name) and do:

```
predict(models[["resp_name"]], new_data)
```

I think this is *much* better than the loop based approach and everything just happened to fall in place nicely. I realize the question explicitly asked for naming variables programmatically, so apologies if that pushed others to answer in that fashion vs. a "bigger picture" answer. The ease of `lapply` suggests I was trying to force a particular solution when a (at least to my eyes) much better one existed.

---

**Bonus:** I didn't realize lists could be multi-dimensional, but in trying it, it appears they can be! This is even better, as I'm using numerous algorithms and I can store *everything* in one big list object.

```
 func_rf <- function(y) { train(x = data_pred, y = y,
     method = "rf", tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = 3),
     ntrees = 100) }

 # svmRadial method requires formula syntax to work with factors,
 # so the train function has to be a bit different
 # add `scale = F` since I had to preProcess the numeric vars ahead of time
 # and cbind to the factors. Without it, caret will try to scale the data
 # for you, which fails for factors

 func_svm <- function(y) { train(y ~ ., cbind(data_pred, y),
     method = "svmRadial", tuneGrid = data.frame(.C = 1, .sigma = .2),
     scale = F) }

 model_list <- list(NULL)
 model_list$rf <- lapply(as.list(data_resp), func_rf)
 model_list$svm <- lapply(as.list(data_resp), func_svm)
```

Now I can refer the desired model *and* response variable with list syntax!

```
 predict(model_list[["svm"]][["response_variable"]], new_data)
```

Super happy with this and hopefully it makes the code more efficient, faster, and I *really* love the "meta-object" I end up with vs. a ton of files, one per model/response variable combination, that I have to load in one at a time later on.

Comment: does the function above work when using lapply? I'm trying to do the same thing with `trainControl`, but the parameters don't appear to pass through when running lapply.

Comment: @Prophet60091 Can you be a bit more specific? It's been a while since I used this, but I definitely *did* use it... so yes, it works as shown. Are you trying to create a list of `trainControl` objects and then iterate through them to see the impact on resultant models? Or just get `lapply()` to iterate though models/data and bring in a `trainControl` object as part of the arguments to `train()`?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old question but still without an accepted answer.
As I understand, you need to programmatically rename a variable and save it so that when reloaded it keeps the new name.
Try this:

```
saveWithName = function(var.name, obj){
  # var.name is a string with the name of the variable you want to assign
  # obj is any kind of R object (data.frame, list, etc.) you want to rename and save
  assign(var.name, obj)
  save(list=var.name, file=sprintf("model_%s.RData", var.name))
}

saveWithName("lab1", c(1,2))
saveWithName("lab2", c(3,4))
load("model_lab1.RData")
load("model_lab2.RData")

print(lab1)
#>[1] 1 2
print(lab2)
#[1] 3 4
```