# Using lapply and !is.na to subset list vectors in R

Tags: r, subset, lapply, na

I'm trying to apply the solution I found here to generate machine learning models:

- [Best way to name objects programmatically using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769121/best-way-to-name-objects-programmatically-using-r)

Here's a dummy data set:

```
data_pred <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, x2 = 11:20, x3 = 21:30)
data_resp <- data.frame(y1 = c(1:5, NA, 7:10), y2 = c(NA, 2, NA, 4:10))
```

Here was my `for()` loop method of modeling the predictors in `data_pred` on each individual column of measured responses in `data_resp` using the `caret` package:

```
# data_pred contains predictors
# data_resp contains one column per measurement
# 1 matching row per observation in both data_pred and data_resp

for (i in 1:ncol(data_resp)) {

   train(x = data_pred[!is.na(data_resp[, i]), ],
         y = data_resp[!is.na(data_resp[, i], i],
         ... )
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with `lapply`, which I think has numerous advantages. I'm having an issue with translating the `!is.na()` criteria on the fly so that I'm only modeling with non-NA cases for each response. Here was my initial function to test the `lapply` method:

```
rf_func <- function(y) {
  train(x = data_pred,
        y = y,
        method = "rf",
        tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = 3:6),
        nodesize = 3,
        ntrees = 500,
        trControl = trControl) }
```

Then create an empty list to store results and apply the function to `data_resp`:

```
models <- list(NULL)
models$rf <- lapply(as.list(data_resp), rf_func)
```

That works fine since `randomForest` can handle `NA`s, but other methods cannot, so I need to remove those rows from each `data_resp` element as well as the corresponding rows from my predictors.

I tried this without success:

```
train(x = data_pred_scale[!is.na(y), ],
      y = y[!is.na(y)],
      ... }
```

I also tried `y[[!is.na(y)]]`

How do I translate the data.frame method (`df[!is.na(df2), ]`) to `lapply`?

Comment: This is a rather weird setup. Most people have one y-variable, and want to train models based on different combinations of the x-variables. You're doing the opposite.

Comment: @HongOoi I have a set of `x`s and numerous measured responses, `y`s. I'd like to use the `x`s to predict each of the `y`s, one at a time. Think of chemical formulas. Imagine I formulate a compound with various ingredients (`x`s) and want to model the resultant viscosity at various temps, modulus, melting point, etc. Does that make more sense? Figuring out *which* `x`s to use is a different (and important) question -- but I would still need to model a subset of `x`s against against each `y`, which is what I'm trying to do above.

Comment: No problem, I was just curious.

Answer (score 3):

several different ways to go about it.   A simple approach is with an anonymous function:

```
 lapply(data_resp, function(x) rf_func(x[!is.na(x)]))
```

Comment: That takes care of ensuring that each element of `data_resp` is subset properly. For `data_pred`, would I just use `data_pred[y, ]`? It seems that this is going to put non-`NA` values of each `data_resp` column into my function (which I've defined as taking `y`... how do I then remove the corresponding omitted rows from my predictors?

Answer (score 0):

In fiddling around quite a bit with a single element of my `as.list(data_frame)` to simulate what `lapply` would be passing, I came up with this, which I *think* is working:

```
rf_func <- function(y) {
  train(x = data_pred_scale[!(unlist(lapply(y, is.na))), ], 
        y = y[!(unlist(lapply(y, is.na)))], 
        method = "rf",
        tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = 3:6),
        nodesize = 3,
        ntrees = 500,
        trControl = trControl) }

models$rf <- lapply(as.list(data_resp), rf_func)
```

It *does* seem to be working. I [hackishly] compared the non-`NA` data set to the `trainingData` results in each `caret` model like so:

```
nas <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(data_resp)) {nas <- c(nas, length(data_resp[!is.na(data_resp[, i]), i]))}

model_nas <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(nas)) {model_nas <- c(model_nas, nrow(models$rf[[i]]$trainingData))}

identical(nas, model_nas)
[1] TRUE
```

So, is `y[!unlist(lapply(y, is.na)))]` the best/most elegant way to do this sort of thing It's pretty ugly...

---

**Edit:** Based on @Ricardo Saporta 's answer, I was able to come up with this (probably obvious to the veterans, but bear with me):

```
rf_func <- function(x, y) {
  train(x = x,
        y = y,
        method = "rf",
        tuneGrid = data.frame(.mtry = 3:6),
        nodesize = 3,
        ntrees = 500,
        trControl = trControl) }

models$rf <- lapply(data_resp, function (y) {
  rf_func(data_pred_scale[!is.na(y), ], y[!is.na(y)] ) 
  }
)
```

Is there still a better way, or is that fairly decent? (Certainly prettier than my first mess up above.)