# {caret} how to pass `trainControl` parameters to custom function in r?

Tags: r, function, lapply, r-caret

I'm working with a list of dataframes (72) which I wish to use as input to caret's `train`, but I'm running into problems when using a custom function. I've found a potential answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769121/best-way-to-name-objects-programmatically-using-r/17773850#17773850), but it refers to `tuneGrid` and not `trainControl`. Both functions I've written fail to pass the specified `trainControl` parameters to `train`:

```
fun.train.rf <- function(x) {
  ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3)
  train(index ~ .,  data = x, method = "rf", 
        trainControl = ctrl) 
}

model.list <- lapply(list.partition, fun.train.rf)
```

or:

```
fun.train.rf <- function(x) {
  train(index ~ .,  data = x, method = "rf", 
        trainControl = list(method="repeatedcv", repeats = 3, p = 0.75)) 
}

model.list <- lapply(list.partition, fun.train.rf)
```

Both functions above "work", but both return models that appear to ignore the specified `trainControl` parameters. When I examine the resulting list of trained models, both examples appear to be using the default training parameters (e.g., `method = boot`):

```
model.list$modelA$control$method
[1] "boot"
...
```

This is my first real attempt at using lapply and lists, so I'm assuming the above examples are likely ill-conceived rather than a shortfall of `caret` itself.

How can I properly pass the `trainControl` parameters to a custom function using caret's `train`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass it in correctly. Instead of

```
trainControl = list(method="repeatedcv", repeats = 3, p = 0.75)
```

try using

```
trControl = trainControl(method="repeatedcv", repeats = 3, p = 0.75)
```

Max